# (BigQuery PY Client Library v0.28) - Fetch result from table 'query' job

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm learning BigQuery API using Python Client Libraries v0.28
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#run-a-simple-query

Wrote this simple code to fetch data from the table

1) Create client object

```
client_ = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('/Users/xyz/key.json')
```

2) Begin new Async query job

```
QUERY =  'SELECT visitid FROM `1234567.ga_sessions_20180101`'
query_job = client_.query(QUERY
                      , job_id=str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

3) poll until the query is DONE

```
while (query_job.state == 'RUNNING'):
    time.sleep(5)
    query_job.reload()
```

4) Fetch the results in iteration

```
query_job.reload()        
iter = query_job.result()
```

At this stage I'd like to fetch how many rows are in the table. As per the doc GitHub code `iter` is of type `bigquery.table.RowIterator` with a property `[tier.total_rows][1]`

5) However, at this stage when I print:

```
print(iter.total_rows)
```

It keeps returning `None`

I'm pretty sure this table is NOT empty an dry query is correctly formatted!

Any help to any pointers what am I missing here will be really helpful... Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to also check query_job.error_result to make sure query succeeded.

You can also see your job in the UI, which can be useful for debugging, using project id and job id:

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/results/projectid:jobid

Also, query_job.result() already waits for the job completion so you don't need to poll.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! error_result() is empty (returns None).. Interesting once I iterate over *iter* <rows = [r.values() for r in it]>, and then both iter.total_rows & iter.num_results prints correct results (Total number of rows in the table).. but prior to iterating both produce 0 results.

Comment: This is interesting. RowIterator runs a GET request to read table rows. My guess is it probably doesn't do it unless you ask for rows, to avoid sending unnecessary request and potentially reading up to 10MB of data.

Answer (score 0):

The current behavior of how `RowIterator` returns `None` is indeed perplexing.  Luckily, according to [this issue, tswast's comment from 10 days ago](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6117#issuecomment-459096993) indicates that the developers are working on a better solution.

#### Current awkward behavior of `.total_rows`

Currently, `.total_rows` is initialized only once iteration begins. (In what follows, for clarity I renamed your `iter` variable to `row_iter`.)

```python
row_iter = query_job.result()
itr = iter(row_iter)
first_row = next(itr)
print(row_iter.total_rows)  # Now you get a number instead of None.
```

This is ugly because to continue the iteration, we must either handle the first row differently or call `row_iter = query_job.result()` again.

#### Temporary workaround

A currently-working alternative is to use the value of `query_job._query_results.total_rows`.  Unfortunately this is cheating because `_query_results` is private, so there is no reason to expect that this will work in the future.

#### Future behavior

If tswast's proposal is implemented, then `row_iter.total_rows` will be initialized at the beginning, just as you expect.

#### Suggestion

In my code, I'm going to use something like

```python
try:
    num_rows = row_iter.total_rows or query_job._query_results.total_rows
except NameError:
    num_rows = None
```

to be compatible with future behavior while falling-back to the temporary workaround if necessary.